# Как сделать не закрывающееся окошечко?

Tags: windows, c, c++

Приветствую. Я где-то увидел кусок кода С++ (или С - хз :) ) и решил его откомпилировать и глянуть, что выйдет ^_^. Вот мой код :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Эм...Как бы вот :). После компиляции под Виндовс появляется .exe файлик. При нажатии на него открываеться консолька (на доли секунды) и закрывается... Как сделать так, чтобы она не закрывалась? :)

ps. ПрОфИ - Пожайлуста не материте - С++ ещё не копался а узнать интересно :).
pps. Дайте обещание что Майкрософт этот кусок кода не покажете - А то мало ли в свои программы внедрят :DDDDDD
ppps. Заранее Спасибо :)

Comment: для второго и третьего пост-скриптума используются сокращения PPS и PPPS, а не PSS и PSSS

Comment: Хороший ответ на вопрос...Я вижу вы профи :) Спасибо.

Comment: перед 
<pre><code>return 0;</code></pre>
допишите строчку
<pre><code>system("pause");</code></pre>

Comment: Ну это надо же какое уважительное отношение к компиляции - пишите ее имя с большой буквы...

Comment: А то! Перестанет работать и фиг вам а не .exe файл... :D Спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с `system("pause")`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib> // Здесь объявлена функция system()
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Функция `system()` вызывает новый экземпляр командного интерпретатора и запускает в нем команду из строки, переданной ей в качестве параметра.

C `getchar()`:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Функция `getchar()` служит для чтения и передачи какой-либо переменной введенного в командной строке символа. Она будет ждать, пока что-то не будет введено. Тут она просто ждет и после нажатия ENTER продолжается выполнение программы, а введенный символ никуда не передается. Поэтому и ложный вызов.

Answer (score 2):

И наконец, самый простой и самый жуткий вариант: for(;;);

Жуткий он тем, что загружает ядро ЦП на 100%.

Comment: реально жуть :) не буду побывать - мало ли :D а плюсиГ держи...

Comment: как вариант  while (1);

Comment: Некоторые компиляторы выдают предупреждение, что в while(1) используется константное выражение. Поэтому лучше использовать for(;;).

Comment: Да видели мы их предупреждения....

Comment: А кстати, какие именно компиляторы? А вариант while(1=1) пройдет?

Comment: Visual C++ например. По крайней мере, с уровнем предупреждений 4.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько вариантов, дописать `system("pause");` сделать фиктивный ввод: `cin.get(); getchar(); etc.`, что-то да должно остановить, экспериментируйте ;)

Comment: Я вроде сказал, что не особо шарю... сделать фиктивный ввод: `cin.get(); getchar(); etc.`  - Для меня это ни о чём не говорит ^_^ 
<br><br>
ps. `system("pause");` - Написал куда только можно (вроде бы). Компилятор ругается, мол, ошибка. Я на `Dev-cpp` компилирую :)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант. Создаешь .bat файл в папке с exe-шниками с таким содержимым "cmd" (без ковычек). При его запуске открывается консоль и из неё уже запускаешь нужный файл.

Answer (score 0):

А ещё можно создать bat или cmd файл в папке с программой с таким содержимым:

```
program
pause
```

где program - это название программы.
 Я этим спобом запускаю чужие консольные программы, чтобы прочитать вывод.

Answer (score -1):

Держи код (работающий, но неправильный :)), заодно выучишь потоковые функции stdio:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    printf("Press ENTER for exit...\n");
    scanf("enter key");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если обьяснишь чем неправильный ещё и плюсиг поставлю :)

Comment: Да просто парень написал, что он не копался еще в плюсах-крестах. А я сам C++ уже последний раз использовал очень давно. Помню простые функции cin/cout для консоли, а для форматированного ввода-вывода printf... Вот и безмозгло решил, что надо заставить юзера нажать Enter, т.е. "\n".